# How to use a get function as a field in a Django Model?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model A like this:

```
class A(models.Model):

     ...
     ...

     def get_total(self):
          return (self.item_set.total - self.discount) # This returns a integer
```

I can access this using `object.get_total()` function. But i want to use this function as a field name. something like this,

```
A.objects.aggregate(Sum(get_total()))  # not working
A.objects.values_list('get_total()') # not working
```

How can i call that function as a field like this?

Comment: You can't, since that is a property, and the database does not know anything about that.

Comment: So the solution is to create another field in the model and i had to update that field  using a function?

Comment: no, usually you annotate the queryset.

Comment: How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use [F expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) to perform your operation in the database:

e.g:

```py
A.objects.aggregate(sum=Sum(F('item_set__total')-F('discount')))
```